# Query regarding logback

Tags: logging, logback

I am writing a logback file to print everything into a file .

```
 <root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </root>
```

I have created an appender for this and it is working fine . The problem is i want a line to be displayed in the console saying that the console output is being printed into a file for others to know. Is there anyway of printing a particular line in logback without creating a class.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider instructing logback to print its own status. This would print all the information about which appenders have been configured and which files the logs are going to. More information on [logback configuration manual](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html).